Distribute i18n application with Angular with new base-href
I created an Angular application using i18n. The issue is that when I build my application with the following command ng build --configuration production --base-href / --localize, the app it always looks for assets in the root folder of the language when trying to run the project. For example: /en-us/main.js, /es-es/main.js.
However, I configured my server so that depending on the browser's language, it loads a directory without the end user seeing the language directory, for example:
example.com/app instead of example.com/app/en-us.
On the server side:
www.example.com/app > /var/www/langs/en-us/example.com
www.example.com/app > /var/www/langs/es-es/example.com
www.example.com/app > /var/www/langs/en-gb/example.com

However, because Angular compiled pointing to the language directory, it always returns 404 when reading the script.
How can I make the built application always point to the JS and CSS in the root of the project instead of the language-specific directory?

If you're still in your early phases, you might consider using another way to achieve i18n, e.g. transloco - in your case, I guess you just need to configure your webserver properly to redirect the requests to a given locale code, see the official deployment docu
